# Ordered mode behavior in journaling file system

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems, journaling

1. In the [following article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-journaling-filesystems/index.html#:%7E:text=Ordered%20mode%20is%20metadata%20journaling%20only%20but%20writes,file%20system%20are%20guaranteed%20consistent%20after%20a%20recovery.), it says "ordered mode is metadata journaling only but writes the data before journaling the metadata." Does this mean the data is physically written to disk before the metadata is written? From what I understand, data written to a disk is first placed in a cache and then flushed to disk. Or is whether the data was actually written to disk irrevelent to the journaling service?
2. Is the metadata that is placed in the journal written directly to disk without first being written to a cache?

Comment: From my understanding, ordered mode means that **data** is **physically** written to the disk before **metadata** is **physically** written to the journal file. Caches are irrelevant for journaling aspects: journaling helps for recover a filesystem after the **power failure**, and in this state all caches, collected before the failure, have been lost.

Comment: If data is "physically written" to disk, wouldn't performance be slow? I was expecting: data is written do a cache to be flushed later but the metadata is physically written to the journal file.

Comment: "If data is "physically written" to disk, wouldn't performance be slow?" - The data needs to be written into the disk **in any case** (whether with journaling or without it). What "performance slow" do you mean? If you are about `write` system call, then it will return upon "cache" is updated (which could occur before physically writing of data and metadata).

Comment: Yes, I was referring to ```write``` call. If I understand correctly, after the cache is physically flushed to disk, the metadata is written physically (without going to a cache) to the journal file?

Comment: I suppose it doesn't matter if journal is cached or not. If cache is not flushed, it's as if nothing happened in the first place.

Comment: "I suppose it doesn't matter if journal is cached or not" - Yes, this is true. Unlike to "normal" data or metadata, which cache can be used upon reading some file, the journal is not used in that case. The journal is read only when need to recover a filesystem.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/65245063/10678955.